# angular-ui-router : breadcrumps ok but view ko

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

this is my app.router.js :

> ```
> agentRouter.config([
>     '$stateProvider',
>     '$urlRouterProvider',
>     function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
>  var root = {
>         name: 'root',
>         abstract: true,
>         url: '',
>         title: 'home',
>         views: {
>             'header':   { templateUrl: 'views/headers/header.app.html', controller: 'HeaderCtrl' },
>             'body':     { templateUrl: "views/root.html" },
>             'footer':   { templateUrl: 'views/footers/footer.app.html' }
>         }
>     }; 
>         var agent = {
>             name: 'root.agent',  
>             url: '/agent',      
>             title: 'agent',   
>             views: {
>                 'root.sidebar':     { templateUrl: "views/main.sidebar.html" },
>                 'root.container':   { templateUrl: "views/partials/agent/list.container.html" }
>             }
>         };
>         var detail = {
>             name: 'root.agent.detail', 
>             url: '/detail/:id',
>             title: 'agentDetail',      // use for breadcrumb
>             views: {
>                 'root.sidebar':     { templateUrl: "views/main.sidebar.html" },
>                 'root.container':   { templateUrl: "views/partials/agent/list.chantier.html" }
>             }
>         };
>         /.../
>         $stateProvider.state(root);
>         $stateProvider.state(agent);
>         $stateProvider.state(detail);
>     }
> ]);
> ```

and this is my root.html :

> 

```
<!--Breadcrumb content-->

<ul class="row breadcrumb">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style=""></i>
    <li ng-repeat="state in $state.$current.path">
        <a ng-href="#{{state.url.format($stateParams)}}"><span ng-bind="state.title"></span></a>
        <span ng-hide="$last" class=""></span>
   </li>
</ul>

 <!--Sidebar content-->
 <div ui-view="root.sidebar">default root.sidebar</div>

    <!--Container content-->
   <div style="background-color: #f9f9f9" ui-view="root.container">default root.container</div>
```

I can access to my "agent" page (a list of person) and my breadcrumb is right : home / agent

but when i click on an item of the list i got always the same page but my breadcrumb is right : 
home / agent / agentDetail

but in app.router.js if change  detail like this :

> var detail = {
>                   name: 'root.detail',   // référence initiale + detail (fils)
>                   url: '/agent/detail/:id',  // réference utilisée dans les fichiers HTML, attention c'est la suite de l'url précédente!!!
>                   title: 'agentDetail',      // référence utilisée pour le breadcump
>                   views: {
>                       'root.sidebar':     { templateUrl: "views/main.sidebar.html" },
>                       'root.container':   { templateUrl: "views/partials/agent/list.chantier.html" }
>                   }
>               };

i got the right page (list.chantier.xml) but the breadcrumb is false :

home / agentDetail  instead of home / agent / agentDetail

I would like to got the right breadcrumb (home / agent / agentDetail) with the right page (list.chantier.html) when i click on an item of the agent list page (list.container.html)

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

by renaming the state to 'root.detail' you attach the detail state to the root state. So it's normal to have 'home / agentDetail' in the breadcrumb.

Take a look on [angular-breadcrumb](https://github.com/ncuillery/angular-breadcrumb) module. Among interesting features (like interpolation in breadcrumb's labels), there is an [option](https://github.com/ncuillery/angular-breadcrumb/wiki/API-Reference#state-options) to change the parent of the state (only for the breadcrumb).